# Can't add features as contents to Vogella Eclipse RCP tutorial project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm learning how to develop RCP Eclipse applications using the [Vogella turorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#exercise-creating-an-eclipse-rcp-application). I can't seem to figure out why when trying to add the necessary features in step 8.2.5 of the tutorial no features are available. Specifically, trying to add:

1. `org.eclipse.e4.rcp`
2. `org.eclipse.emf.ecore`
3. `org.eclipse.emf.common`

The tutorial says to base the configuration of *features*, not *plug-ins*. However, I can only see the features (only `org.eclipse.emf.ecore` and `org.eclipse.emf.common`) if I set the configuration to *plug-ins*. Here's an image:

[with plug-ins configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVSO3.png)

However, this is what I see when I set it up with the *features* configuration:

[with features configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTnNx.png)

I would appreciate very much any input on why this might be happening. Thanks!

Comment: Note: The `org.eclipse.emf.ecore` and `org.eclipse.emf.common` you are seeing in the plug-ins configuration are not features, they are plug-ins that happen to have the same name as the feature.

Comment: Got it, thanks @greg-449 Would you know of some reasons why the list of features appears empty when trying to add them to my plug-in project?

Comment: No, I can't think of a reason. There should be twenty or more features shown even on a small Eclipse install and it should certainly include the one you just created. Maybe an error is occurring - look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is an error message.